# I can't connect a microSD card

Tags: arduino-nano, esp32, sd-card

I can’t connect a microSD card to either the Arduino or the ESP32. It needs to be connected to the ESP32; I just tested it on the Arduino to see if it works at all.

Equipment: ESP32 devkit v1, Arduino Nano, MicroSD card adapter, MicroSD card SanDisk 64gb eXFat.

Software: Arduino IDE, library SdFat (version: 2.2.2). The sketch is an example from the sdfat library - (sdinfo).

Connection to pin: SD adapter pin - CS, SCK, MOSI, MISO, VCC, GND
Arduino to SD Adapter - (CS, D10) (SCK, D13) (MOSI, D11) (MISO, D12) (VCC, +5V) (GND, GND)
ESP32 to SD Adapter - (CS, D27) (SCK, D14) (MOSI, D12) (MISO, D13) (VCC, VIN) (GND, GND)

Result ESP32:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806ac
```

Result Arduino:

```
SdFat version: 2.2.2

Assuming the SD is the only SPI device.
Edit DISABLE_CS_PIN to disable an SPI device.

Assuming the SD chip select pin is: 10
Edit SD_CS_PIN to change the SD chip select pin.

type any character to start
```

These are the full port monitor results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what's wrong

1. Common for connecting to any equipment

SdFat doesn't work for me, I still don't understand what's wrong with this library
so it's better to use standard SD library

2. Common for connecting to any equipment

SD card (no name, SDHC, 32 GB)

Formatting an Sd card for an SD library (possibly for SdFat) should be in Fat32 with a msdos partition table
I found the answer here (https://forum.arduino.cc/t/yet-another-sd-initialization-fail/286017)
Due to an incorrect partition table, my card could not be read

3. ESP32 pin connection
   ESP32 to MicroSD Adapter - (CS , D5) (SCK , D18) (MOSI , D23) (MISO , D19) (VCC , VIN) (GND , GND)
4. Arduino Pin Connection
   Arduino to MicroSD Adapter - (CS , D4) (SCK , D13) (MOSI , D11) (MISO , D12) (VCC , +5V) (GND , GND)